# Get credentials from EC2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've implemented a javascript function which gets AWS credentials from ajax and uploads a file to s3.
now i want to avoid getting the credentials from the ajax and retrieve them from the ec2.
here is the code :

```
function upload_file(entity_key_arg){
    var accessKeyId,secretAccessKey,s3region,Bucket,link_to_file;
    $.ajax({
        async : true,
        'type' : "POST",
        'global' : false,
        'dataType' : 'json',
        'url' : getUrl('getConfigFile'),
        'data' : {
            'token' : sessionStorage.getItem("token")
        },
        'success' : function(data) {
            if(data.msg == "Error"){
                throw_to_login_page();
            }
            var ssToken = data.data.ssToken;
            accessKeyId = data.data.S3AccessKey;
            secretAccessKey = data.data.secretAccessKey;
            s3region = data.data.S3Region;
            link_to_file = data.data.link_to_file;
            Bucket = data.data.Bucket;
            AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
                secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
                region: s3region
            });
            //AWS.Credentials(sessionToken = ssToken);
            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
              var file = document.getElementById('file_select').files[0];
              if (file == null) {
                return alert('Please choose a file to upload first.');
              }
              if(file.size >= 1024 * 1024 * 5){
                  alert("The Maximum file size is 5MB")
              }
              else{
                  var file_description = $("#attach_file_description_field").val(); 
                  var file_name_from_input = $("#file_name_field").val();   
                  file_type = file.name.split(".")[file.name.split(".").length-1];
                  var fileName = data.data.client_key+"/Files/"+entity_key_arg+"_"+file_name_from_input+"."+file_type;
                  var link_to_file = link_to_file + fileName

                  var params = {
                    Bucket: Bucket,
                    Key: fileName,
                    Body: file,
                    ACL: 'public-read'
                  };

                  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                      return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#add_file_modal").css("display","none");
                        $.post(getUrl('insert_file'),
                        {   
                            'token' : sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
                            'entity_key': entity_key_arg, 
                            'entity_type': new RegExp("ALR").test(entity_key_arg) || new RegExp("MAN").test(entity_key_arg)? "ALERT":"CUST",
                            'file_path': link_to_file,
                            'file_name': $("#file_name_field").val(),
                            'file_desc': $("#attach_file_description_field").val()
                        },function(ans){
                            if(ans.msg == "Error"){
                                throw_to_login_page();
                            }
                            get_attachments(entity_key_arg);
                            populate_audit_table(entity_key_arg);
                        });
                    }
                  });
              }
            }
        }
    ); 
}
```

I've created an IAM role to the aws with full access to s3 and attached it to the ec2.
The above JS function is part of web application which deployed inside the ec2 using tomcat. the CORS is also OK but with all this, once I comment the credentials part in my function  - I can't upload the file

```
/*AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
            region: s3region
        });*/
```

I keep getting **access denied**. 
When I tried to upload a file through CLI from the ec2 to s3 I've succeeded and no credentials where needed so the IAM role attached to ec2 gets the access to S3.

What could be the reason for the denied access for the js file deployed inside the machine? and how can I debug this?
(The CORS is fully opened..) it's really frustrating .

Comment: When you upload with the cli, are you doing the cli equivalent of `ACL: 'public-read'`?  Specifically, `--acl public-read`?  Supplying that argument requires more permissions than simply uploading an object with the default ACL.

Comment: My EC2's inbounds rules has pretty much all types available and enabled :http,https tcp with relevant ports and even ssh..

Comment: That isn't really related to this.  S3 has two different permissions related to the operations in question, and it is possible to have permission to upload an object but not to set its ACL.  Please verify whether your aws-cli command works if you include `--acl public-read` in the command.

Comment: Done it. works also with --acl public-read in the CLI upload command

Comment: What could be the problem?